# Magento 2 add label out of stock products in configurable product dropdown

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, out-of-stock

There are some related messages but not precisely this.

Is there an method to - show out of stock products (for a configurable product) - add a label "out of stock"

So a drop down with

- XS
- S
- M
- L

becomes

- XS
- S
- M
- L - out of stock

Help appreciated.

Comment: I test this solution at magento 2.3.1 and it is not working...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158013)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use Magento 2 plug-ins to add out of stock labels to child options.

See sample code here: https://github.com/Jitheesh/Magento2-configurable

(This is working fine for me on Magento 2.2.2 version)

Comment: Works on Magento 2.3.4 as well. Adjustments are needed. You may have multiple colors available and it will say Out of Stock, even though another color is available

Comment: Can you tell what are the changes to be made in that module?

Comment: I installed that module but it is not showing any labels for out of stock child products.